# Safe to upgrade to Windows 8 on Bootcamp?

Tags: bootcamp, windows, dual-boot

So I'd read a **[service advisory on the Parallels site](http://kb.parallels.com/en/114973)** warning users not to upgrade to Windows 8 due to it damaging their virtual machine and associated files therein.

That being said, is it currently possible/safe to upgrade to Windows 8 from Windows 7 on a Bootcamp installation through typical upgrade means, or are there any notices to hold off on this as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its perfectly safe. You might run into problems with the trackpad driver (i did) but a quick search here was all i needed to fix it.